# How to notify another mail about incoming mail with a specific subject or label in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

Whenever I get an email from `xxx@example.com` (specific filter) I want to automatically send an email message to other email address. Not to forward the mail but to send a notification like "you have a new message with the filter "xxx" in the mail box `yyy@example.net`).

I tried to add filter and used canned response but it is only for "response".

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue here 5 years later. Neither Gmail or IFTTT solved the problem for me.

I signed up on https://zapier.com/ using my Google account. Using this, I was able to make a "zap" that's triggered when a specific email comes in and responds to the trigger by sending an email of my choosing. It was fairly straight forward to set up and surprisingly testable.

EDIT: I do not work for Zapier, I just solve problems and want to contribute here.

Comment: Wow, Zapier gives complete control over this with easy setup!  Alternatively, I use Google Apps scripts when I need to get super customized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to be able to solve this purely with Gmail. You're going to need to use a third-party service.

One thing that comes to mind is [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com).

You could set up a recipe like this:

**Trigger** (from the [Gmail channel](https://ifttt.com/gmail)): "New email in inbox from" `xxx@example.com`

(Alternatively, you can use the "New email in inbox labeled" or "New email in inbox from search" triggers.)

**Action** (from the [Gmail channel](https://ifttt.com/gmail)): "Send an email" to `yyy@example.net`: "There is a new message from 'xxx@example.com'"

If you want the email to come *from* IFTTT rather than your own Gmail address, you can use the [Email channel](https://ifttt.com/email).

Other options are: You don't need to use email at all for the action. You could use SMS, or Android notifications, or any number of other options. (For instance, I have a recipe that sends me an Android alert whenever I get an email messages from my wife.)

I don't work for IFTTT. I'm just an enthusiastic user.

Comment: Your links are down..

Comment: Oh, phooey. They removed the deeplinks to actions and triggers. That's a bummer.